# Move "Missed Conversation..." emails to another folder than Inbox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2010, lync-2010

I did run around with Google but found nothing helpful so I post this question here.
I'm an end-user, using Office 2013 with Exchange Server 2010 SP2 with Lync2010.
Everytime I got a chat message and don't reply in 5s, an email with "Missed conversation with ..." appear in my Inbox.
This make my Inbox filled up too fast, and make my Inbox "not clean" anymore. (I'm trying keep it clean with this [guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingOrganizedWhileDrinkingFromTheOutlookFireHose.aspx))
Is there any settings or tips or tools can auto-move these "Missed conversation.." email out of my inbox?
My admin can't help about this!
I don't want to uncheck "Save instant message conversation..." cause I need chat message logged for further reference.
Any ideas are appreciated!
Sorry for my bad English. :(

---

Update: 
I did try with Outlook Rule but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try to make a Rule? Right-click one of the messages, in the context menu chose Rule/Create a Rule. define the pattern (for example, "Missed Conversation" in the subject, or something, and save and activate the rule. The rule can for example mark them read and move them into a subfolder "Conversations" or whatever you like.

Comment: I did try with rule, doesnt work! :(

Comment: Server side rules for the headers to move to another folder?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new rule to apply on messages you receive.  For the trigger, select "with specific words in the subject" and add "Missed conversation with" and "Missed conference with" (for group conversations).

This can produce false positives, but it hasn't been a problem for me.

Comment: This does not work since outlook does not treat these notifications as "received messages"

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the thread, but for future reference:

try 1) removing "From Microsoft Outlook" from the rule. in the message details Outlook is the Sender, but not the From (this is why it says "on behalf of" in the From)

2) add "with 'X-CallingTelephoneNumber' or 'X-VoiceMessageSenderName' or 'X-CallID' or 'Content-Class: missedcall' in the message header" to the rule. You may only need one of those, but they were all in the missed call notification I was working with.